# Calling API inside another API call using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a function when a button is clicked.

I wrote everything nesting one API inside another API call. For the first call I got the response with the data, and in there I make the second call using the response received in the first call. After the second call I set the triggerButton function that was going to be called when the button is clicked.

This is an example of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', triggerButton);

    $.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data){

    //inside this function I call another api using the data response.
    $.get('example.url', function(response){

         //do something with this data of the response and ended function
    });
    // now I set a new handler
    function triggerButton() {

        // do something

    }  });
});
```

Should I be setting the triggerButton handler outside all the functions? If so, how could I use all information of the API calls responses in my handler (since I need it to compare variables). Or should I be creating the triggerButton handler inside of the inner API function? If so, how could I call it from the outside?

Comment: `triggerButton` handler is just a function and it has normal scope rules as all other JS functions. But I doesn't fully understand your question. Your code is strange. You want to make AJAX request only after button is clicked? Then just put all the code except `$('#button').on('click', triggerButton)` into the `triggerButton` function and that's all.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor paragraph quality, I am trying to learn.

Comment: I don't want to actually call the ajax when the button is clicked, I just want to change a variable in the Html, to be specific change a value of temperature in a element from Fahrenheit to Celsius o vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the event handler as soon as the page is loaded, the definition of `triggerButton` should be placed outside of the "api function". Here is a possible solution for your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var webData = null;
    $.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data){

        //inside this function I call another api using the data response.
        $.get('example.url', function(response){
             //do something with this data of the response and ended function
        });

        // expose the data to be used by button click event hander or other
        // funcitons that care about the data 
        webData = data;
    });

    // Set the event handler
    $('#button').on('click', triggerButton);
    // define the handler
    function triggerButton() {
        if(webData){
            // do something with the webData

        }else{
            // display some information that tells the user the status
            alert('loading...');

        }
    }  
});
```

Another approach is use two event handler to handle the click event before and 
after the API response is received respectively. If you don't care about the button click before API response is received, you can omit the first event handler. Here is a example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set the event handler before resource is loaded
    $('#button').on('click', triggerButton);
    // define the handler
    function triggerButton() {
        // display some information that tells the user the status
        alert('loading...');
    }  

    $.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data){
        //inside this function I call another api using the data response.
        $.get('example.url', function(response){
             //do something with this data of the response and ended function
        });

        // update the event handler
        $('#button').off('click', triggerButton).on('click', function(){
            // do some things...
        });
    });
});
```

Besides, if you want the API request is sent after the click of button, you can move them inside the event handler (here use another function to make it more clear):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var webData = null;
    var loading = false;

    function loadData(){
        $.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data){
            //inside this function I call another api using the data response.
            $.get('example.url', function(response){
                 //do something with this data of the response and ended function
            });

            // expose the data to be used by button click event hander or other
            // funcitons that care about the data 
            webData = data;
        });
    }

    // Set the event handler
    $('#button').on('click', triggerButton);
    // define the handler
    function triggerButton() {
        if(webData){
            // do something with the webData

        }else{
            // display some information that tells the user the status
            alert('loading...');
            if(!loading){
                loading = true;
                loadData();
            }
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and support, I really appreciate it. You know I am trying that method of saving the data response in a variable, but when I call the variable at the end of the code console.log(webData) and the value shown is "null", like if the variable is not being modified inside the function. Do you have any idea?,   again Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not clear about your problem. I have make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL1p16yc/) which may be helpful to you.